# Normalizing time series data to the range $[-1, 1]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a timeseries that if possible I would like to standardize with the maximum value being $1$ and the minimum value being equal to $-1$ and the other values in the time series adjusted to fit in between.

I have tried

> $$y = \frac{x - \textrm{min}}{\textrm{max} - \textrm{min}} ,$$

but this standardizes the values between $0$ and $1$ (not $-1$ and $1$).

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** Your normalization will be a linear function $$x \mapsto m (x - \mu),$$ and the normalization condition implies that coefficients $m$ and $\mu$ satisfy the system
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
m (x_{\textrm{min}} - \mu) &=& -1 \\
m (x_{\textrm{max}} - \mu) &=& \phantom{-}1
\end{array}
\right. .
$$

> Solving gives $$m = \frac{2}{x_{\textrm{max}} - x_{\textrm{min}}}, \qquad \mu = \frac{1}{2}(x_{\textrm{min}} + x_{\textrm{max}}) .$$

Answer (score 5):

Take the current formula, multiply it by two, and subtract one from the result. This works because the function $x\mapsto 2x-1$ is linear/increasing and carries the interval $(0,1)$ to $(-1,1)$.